# Not to get killed in SPARK (YARN)

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there is any command nopt to get killed our application ID while running queries in SPARK

Comment: please explain more clearly.. why do you want that? is it getting killed automatically?? if so , what is the log message??  etc

Comment: no problem. For each query, while we are running it automatically creates an application ID right? It should be killed automatically after the query completed. I'm asking this because once a user start a spark session it automatically consumes more memory. To avoid that if one job has completed if it kills automatically means we can reduce the memory consumption